# OpenApi 3.0 requestBody required

Tags: postman, openapi, postman-pre-request-script

I use postman and i create API with the openAPI 3.0.
Problem is when i send this request, if i add body or not it return status code 200. I don't understand because i said i my code required for requestbody and for field in this body but nothing worth (without body code 200 and without GRP_CNOM code 200)...
SomeOne can help me ?

my openAPI code :

````
        post:
            operationId: CreationGroup
            summary: Creation groupe
            requestBody:
                $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/crea'
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: '200 - Création du groupe effectué'
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                type: object
                                properties:
                                    code:
                                        type: integer
                                    message:
                                        type: string
                                example:
                                    code: 200
                                    message: Le groupe a bien été créé
                '400':
                    description: '400 - Création du groupe échouée'
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                type: object
                                properties:
                                    code:
                                        type: integer
                                    message:
                                        type: string
                                example:
                                    code: 200
                                    message: Le groupe a échouée
                '401':
                    $ref: '#/components/responses/UnauthorizedError'
                default:
                    description: 'Erreur'
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Error'
components:
    requestBodies:
        crea:
            required: true
            content:
                application/json:
                    schema:
                        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Group'
                    example:
                        $ref: '#/components/examples/oneGroupOrga'
    securitySchemes:
        jwtAuth:       
            type: http
            scheme: bearer
            bearerFormat: JWT
    examples:
        oneGroupOrga:
            value:
                GRP_CNOM: Princ
                GRP_SPKGROUPE: 2
                GRP_SFKINSTANCE: 1
                GRP_CBORDERCOLOR: "#F5370E"
                GRP_BSOCIETE: true
                GRP_BETABLISSEMENT: true
                GRP_BUNITE: false
                GRP_CSIRET: null
                GRP_SFKAPE: 1
                GRP_CCAPITAL: "200000"
                GRP_SMOISDEBUTEXERCICECOMPTABLE: 1
                GRP_CABREVIATIONSOCIETE: PR
                GRP_CNUMEROTVAINTRACOMMUNAUTAIRE: ""
                GRP_DCOEFFICIENTENCOURSCOMPTABLE: 70
                GRP_CADRESSE: 113 boulevard de Lamasquère
                GRP_CCODEPOSTAL: "31600"
                GRP_SFKVILLE: 1
                GRP_SFKPAYS: 1
                GRP_CENTETETEXTE: "PRINC"
                GRP_CENTETEIMAGE: "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"
                GRP_CPIEDDEPAGEIMAGE: "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"
                GRP_CPIEDDEPAGETEXTE: "113 boulevard de Lamasquère - 31600 MURET - 890720824"
                GRP_SFKFONCTION: 1
                GRP_DNOTATION: null
                GRP_CCOMMENTAIRE: null
                GRP_SFKFORMBUILDER: 1
                GRP_CSIREN: "890 720 824"
                GEG_SFKGROUPEPARENT120: 1
                GRP_SFKGROUPETYPE: 650
                ADM_COMPTEBANCAIRE:
                    -
                        CBC_SPKCOMPTE: 1
                        CBC_CNOMDUCOMPTE: Compte courant
                        CBC_CNOMDELABANQUE: CIC
                        CBC_CDOMICILIATION: ""
                        CBC_CBIC: ""
                        CBC_CRIB: ""
                        CBC_CIBAN: ""
                        CBC_BPARDEFAUT: true
                ADM_UTILISATEUR_GROUPE:
                    -
                        UGR_SFKUTILISATEUR: 1
                        UGR_SFKFONCTION: 2
    schemas:
        Group:
            type: object
            discriminator:
                propertyName: GRP_CNOM
            required:
                -
                    GRP_CNOM
            properties:
                GRP_CNOM:
                    type: string
                GRP_SPKGROUPE:
                    type: integer
                GRP_SFKINSTANCE:
                    type: integer
                GRP_SFKROLE:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CBORDERCOLOR:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_BSOCIETE:
                    type: boolean
                GRP_BETABLISSEMENT:
                    type: boolean
                GRP_BUNITE:
                    type: boolean
                GRP_CSIRET:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_SFKAPE:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CCAPITAL:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_SMOISDEBUTEXERCICECOMPTABLE:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CABREVIATIONSOCIETE:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CNUMEROTVAINTRACOMMUNAUTAIRE:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_DCOEFFICIENTENCOURSCOMPTABLE:
                    type: number
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CADRESSE:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CCODEPOSTAL:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_SFKVILLE:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_SFKPAYS:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CENTETETEXTE:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CENTETEIMAGE:
                    type: string
                    format: byte
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CPIEDDEPAGEIMAGE:
                    type: string
                    format: byte
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CPIEDDEPAGETEXTE:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_SFKFONCTION:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_DNOTATION:
                    type: number
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CCOMMENTAIRE:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GRP_SFKFORMBUILDER:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_CSIREN:
                    type: string
                    nullable: true
                GEG_SFKGROUPEPARENT120:
                    type: integer
                    nullable: true
                GRP_SFKGROUPETYPE:
                    type: integer
                    enum:
                        -
                            650
                        -
                            651
                        -
                            652
                GEG_SFKGROUPEENFANT122:
                    type: array
                    items:
                        type: string
                GEG_SFKGROUPEENFANT121:
                    type: array
                    items:
                        type: object
                        properties:
                            GRP_SPKGROUPE:
                                type: integer
                            GRP_SFKGROUPETYPE:
                                type: integer
                                enum:
                                    -
                                        650
                                    -
                                        651
                                    -
                                        652
                        required:
                            -
                                GRP_SPKGROUPE
                            -
                                GRP_SFKGROUPETYPE
                ADM_COMPTEBANCAIRE:
                    type: array
                    items:
                        type: object
                        properties:
                            CBC_SPKCOMPTE:
                                type: integer
                            CBC_CNOMDUCOMPTE:
                                type: string
                            CBC_CNOMDELABANQUE:
                                type: string
                            CBC_CDOMICILIATION:
                                type: string
                            CBC_CBIC:
                                type: string
                            CBC_CRIB:
                                type: string
                            CBC_CIBAN:
                                type: string
                            CBC_BPARDEFAUT:
                                type: boolean
                                default: false
                        required:
                            -
                                CBC_CNOMDUCOMPTE
                ADM_UTILISATEUR_GROUPE:
                    type: array
                    items:
                        type: object
                        properties:
                            UGR_SFKUTILISATEUR:
                                type: integer
                            UGR_SFKFONCTION:
                                type: integer
                            UGR_SFKDROIT:
                                type: integer
                                enum:
                                    -
                                        59
                                    -
                                        60
                        required:
                            -
                                UGR_SFKUTILISATEUR
        Error:
            type: object
            properties:
                code:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32
                message:
                    type: string
    responses:
        UnauthorizedError:
            description: Le token est invalid ou manquant
security:
    - 
        jwtAuth: [] ```
````

Comment: It looks like the API server accepts this request both with and without the body. This is typically controlled in the API code, not necessarily in the OpenAPI definition.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes so how can i do that ?

Answer (score 5):

You can place the `required` in the `paths` instead of the `components`. For example:

```yaml
[...]
post:
    operationId: CreationGroup
    summary: Creation groupe
    requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/requestBodies/crea'
        responses:
[...]
```

If `required` would be in `components` then it would be required every time its used. However, in reality, whether a request body is required depends on the route. That is why they like you to put it in the `paths` section.